# How to prevent same user updating their own record in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**Details:**

I have 3 tables:

```
create table request (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    date_requested timestamp,
    user_id int,
    filename varchar(255),
    status enum('New','Verified','Rejected') not null default 'New',
    foreign key(user_id) references users(id)
);

create table users (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null
);

create table verify (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    user_id int,
    request_id int,
    created timestamp,
    status enum('Verified','Rejected') not null,
    foreign key(request_id) references request(id)
);
```

Here is an example data for request table: (Sorry wasn't sure how to provide an example with headers below).

```
id|    date_requested|   user_id|              filename|                status|
1 |  2020-04-06 13:33:51    3     C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\123 321.jpg    New
```

And here is users:

```
id   username   password
1      test1      123
2      test2      123@#
3      test1      123321
```

Next, to mark this document. I have this query to add a record into `verify` table. You can see the references `user_id` and `request_id`

```
insert into verify (user_id, request_id, created, status, comments) values (3,1,now(), 'Rejected', 'Tester');
```

**Problem:**

But the query above should not be allowed, because the user is marking their own record. How can this be prevented? How can I query it differently?

Comment: That kind of business logic is something which you would normally implement in your application layer. You can't really enforce it with constraints within the database, I don't think.

Comment: @ADyson I will be using C# window form.

Comment: ok well that's where you need to write the logic. Protect the function which generates the insert query with some code which checks the ID of the logged-in user, and ensures their ID is not on the request they are trying to verify. Only run the insert if those IDs don't match.

Comment: @ADyson just a simple `if` `else` statement I guess then..

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. I guess you might need to SELECT the details of the request first (to get the user ID who created it), if they're not already stored in a variable in the C# program at that moment. But apart from that yes it's a pretty trivial change.

Comment: @ADyson that sounds good. I have another post - about an hour ago. Im asking how I can get `id` from selected combox value that is referenced to a query. I think you might be the right guy.

Comment: Do a BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER and check all the constraints that you need

Comment: @LV98 actually I almost never use WinForms (I'm more of a web developer), so I'm not sure myself. But I'd hope that googling "winforms combobox get selected value" would probably tell you the answer. You can't possibly be the first person to want to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce it on the database level by changing the primary key (or use a different unique key) to include the user id as well and a `CHECK` constraint in the verify table which compares the verifier user id and the request user id.

First you create the `request` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE request (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    dummy VARCHAR(100), -- just for testing
    PRIMARY KEY (id, user_id), -- two column primary key
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Now the `verify` table must use the two column primary key as the foreign key, otherwise a reference is not possible. Because the request user id is inside the `verify` table you can add a `CHECK` which enforces that you cannot verify yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE verify (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    verifier_user_id INT NOT NULL,
    request_id INT NOT NULL,
    request_user_id INT NOT NULL,
    dummy VARCHAR(100), -- again, just for testing
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (verifier_user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (request_id, request_user_id) REFERENCES request(id, user_id),
    CHECK (verifier_user_id != request_user_id)
);
```

Since `verifier_user_id` and `request_user_id` cannot be the same and you must include the whole foreign key from the `request` table, it is not possible to verify yourself anymore:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | first    | user     |
|  2 | second   | user     |
+----+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM request;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | user_id | dummy |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | test  |
+----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO verify (verifier_user_id, request_id, request_user_id, dummy) VALUES (2, 1, 1, 'test a');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO verify (verifier_user_id, request_id, request_user_id, dummy) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'test a');
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'verify_chk_1' is violated.
```